# Unable to use SecureStorage/Preferences in .Net6

Tags: xamarin-native

I am getting below error while migrating Xamarin Native to .Net6

Package: **Xamarin.Essentials**

This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.